# Manage content type's different status for different users

Tags: 7, users

I want to know if there are any modules for the following situation:

I have a content type A with reference to user 1 to user N. Now that content type A will have different status for different users let's say for user 1 it has Status1, user 2 it has Status2. First thing is how can I achieve this functionality is there any module which will be useful for this situation ?

Other part of the scenario is when user1 logs in he should see content type A with status S1 and when user2 logs in he should see content type B with status S2.

Is this possible at all in Drupal? Please suggest me.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are you looking something like moderation of content?

Comment: @Nagarjuna, No. I am looking for a module that will enable me to set different status of a content for different users.

Comment: So you mean that, if u have thousands of users, you need thousand status for one node?

Comment: yes. some what like that. If you have better idea on how can I achieve this type of functionality it would be helpful.

Comment: Group users into types and create a role and assign to the users. And then for the particular user role show the status in different way !!!

Comment: can we discuss on
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46011/drupal-query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46012/discussion-between-nagarjuna-and-parth-k).

Answer (score 1):

Based on chat with @parth I realised the status field belongs more to relation of book and user rather than book. Here is my recommendation in that case.

**Way 1:**

The easiest way I could think of is

- have a custom table as book_inventory with columns as book_entity_id, user_id,status,record_id

**In order to allow admin to a UI in place to udpate status with fields as**

- autocomplete field for book
- autocomplete field for user
- status could be dropdown field

this UI will let admin to set status for any book against any user
down to your form UI, you can list what books are assigned to what users from your custom table with an edit link
when the admin clicks the edit button the same form UI will open but prepopulated with all the fields
now with help of this table
you always have information user and book status with you, you can query your database and get the status runtime
and in case you do not have a record agaisnt requested user and book, in that case you can have a default status, I believe 'not purchased' in your case

**Way 2:**

Other approach would be to try Relation module instead of entityReference, as relation module will allow fieldable relation between book and user.

Comment: thanks for interest. But can we continue discussion on
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46011/drupal-query